# How do I pass an existing table to a procedure? How do I use this... table-valued parameters thingys? look at my code below please

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, parameter-passing, table-valued-parameters

I have many tables that need ID scramblers, so:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_generateUniqueID ( -- pass table here somehow -- )
AS  
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ID         varchar(100)    -- NEW ID.
    DECLARE @isIDInUse  tinyint         -- BOOLEAN YES/NO.
    SET     @isIDInUse=1
    WHILE(@isIDInUse=1)                 -- KEEP GENERATING TILL YOU FIND ONE:
        BEGIN
            SET @ID= dbo.generateID('aA1a1') -- GENERATES ID. doesn't matter how.
            IF (@ID NOT IN (@passedTable))   -- DOES @ID EXIST ALREADY?
        /*(SEARCHES THE PASSED TABLE! Which its size will be 1XN)*/
                SET @isIDInUse=0             -- NO, YOU CAN USE.
        END
    RETURN @ID
END
```

I can't make the passing of the existing table go smoothly...
I want to be able to insert any table that uses IDs.
Any suggestion?

Comment: There are a few options (CLR, dynamic SQL).  But it might help if you explain the purpose.  With added context, you are more likely to get the right solution.

Comment: did you checked table valued parameter?

Comment: Table-valued parameters are a dead-end - you can't just pass a table, you can only pass a table variable.

Comment: If you are trying to generate a unique id, why don't you either use UNIQUEIDENTIFIER by using NewId() or NewSequentialID() or a SEQUENCE. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx.

Comment: You have a number of things going on here that are less than ideal. First you named your procedure with the sp_ prefix. This is not a good practice. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix Then you have a loop generating some information. And inside your loop is a scalar function. Top that off with possible concurrency issues and this whole idea needs to be rethought.

Comment: Did not know about the existence of UNIQUEIDENTIFIER , NewSequentialID(), or SEQUENCE up until now. Thanks :)

However, the question remains:
How to pass a table of size 1XN to a stored-procedure?
(Much like a lookup table, if that helps anyone to better understand)

Comment: @Talkohavy  Do you actually still need this question answered?  Passing a table to a stored procedure in this manner is generally.....just....not done.  What is it you are actually trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you ***REALLY*** look hard into better solutions for this issue.  You will be hitting your table/index with every iteration of the new ID that you generate.  What is wrong with an auto-incrementing integer value:

`create table IDs (ID int identity(1,1))`

(also, SQL Server has `bit` data types for boolean values.  No need for your `tinyint`)

---

That aside, the only way I think you can do this your way is with dynamic SQL.  Using the script below you should be able to see how you can pass in your `schema.table` to the stored procedure and within the procedure define your `ID` to be inserted in to the checking loop:

```
create table a(ID nvarchar(100)) insert into a values('1'),('2'),('3'),('4'),('5')
create table b(ID nvarchar(100)) insert into b values('6'),('7'),('8'),('9'),('10')


declare @Table nvarchar(100) = 'dbo.a'

declare @ID nvarchar(100) = '6'
declare @IDinUse bit = 0

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'if exists(select ID from ' + @Table + ' where ID = @ID) select @IDinUse = 1 else select @IDinUse = 0'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@ID nvarchar(100), @IDinUse bit output', @ID = @ID, @IDinUse = @IDinUse output
select @IDinUse as IDinUse

go

declare @Table nvarchar(100) = 'dbo.b'

declare @ID nvarchar(100) = '6'
declare @IDinUse bit = 0

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'if exists(select ID from ' + @Table + ' where ID = @ID) select @IDinUse = 1 else select @IDinUse = 0'
exec sp_executesql @sql, N'@ID nvarchar(100), @IDinUse bit output', @ID = @ID, @IDinUse = @IDinUse output
select @IDinUse as IDinUse
```